# Index out of bounds when reading entries from a file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, ifstream

I have the following text file:

```
1. DC's Legends of Tomorrow
2. Ice Age 5: Collision Course
3. Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children
4. Forbidden Empire
5. The Zero Theorem
6. X-Men: Days of Future Past
7. Jupiter Ascending
8. The Mortal Instruments: City Of Bones
9. The Age of Adaline
10. Melancholia
```

Each entry has a line of blank space between them. I am trying to read through the file and save each movie into an array of strings. 
I am getting the error: Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: String substring out of range

Here is my code:

```
void readFile() {
        ifstream in_stream;
        int numberLines = 10;
        string movieName;
        int movieNum;
        string movieList[10];
        in_stream.open("input.txt"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            in_stream >> movieNum >> movieName;
            movieList[i] = movieName;
        }

        in_stream.close();
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, or at least use "printf-style" debugging in your code.  What are the values of `movieNum` and `movieName` in the first loop iteration?  The second iteration?  I'm quite sure they are not what you expect in the second iteration, as reading into `movieName` will *not* process all the words in the first line.

Comment: I realize this isn't part of the question, but it would be better if there was a standard header where you could read in the number of entries, delimiter, etc. This is much better than hardcoding the amount of entries

Comment: You should use std::getline()` to read until the end of each line.  Also, you should check the return value of each stream operation.

Answer (score 0):

while reading data from a file, you're only get string data. `MovieNum` was declared as Integer.But You're trying to store the string data into it. If You want integer value `(MovieNum`), you can typecast from string into integer.

```
void readFile() {
        ifstream in_stream;
        int numberLines = 10;
        string movieName;
        string movieNum;
        string movieList[10];
        in_stream.open("input.txt"); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            in_stream >> movieNum >> movieName;
            movieList[i] = movieName;
        }

        in_stream.close();
    }
```

Hope this might helps :)